# Does a new triggered callback interrupt an previous running callback function?

Tags: c#

In this following scenario

```
a.Arrived+= arrived_call;
Thread.CurrentThread.Join(60000);
a.Arrived-= arrived_call;
```

when `a.Arrived` happens, I call the `arrived_call` callback, that is clear.

However, it looks to me that if a second `arrived_call` is called (lets name it CALL2) before the previously called `arrived_call` (CALL1) has completed its code, CALL1 is interrupted.

I am saying this because my `arrived_call` has a loop like this

```
private void arrived_call(object sender, ScnEventArgs e) {
  using(IMn scn = (IMn) e.GetScn()) {
    //Do work on scn
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Often the loop is fully executed, i.e. all `i` are printed, but  sometimes the loop stops way before `i` is 49.

Comment: Very much at the mercy of whatever class has that `Arrived` event and what its documentation says. "Interrupting" or aborting the previous call is the most destructive and also one of the more complex behaviours to do but it's within the realms of possibility. More often either multiple calls are invoked on separate threads, the calls end up serialized, or "missed" calls never happen. But those are all possible and again are at the mercy of the specific class with that event. There's not one single straightforward answer that is always true here.

Comment: You've also not said what made you think that the calls are "interrupted". If it's that you see an output of 0 before a previous sequence reaches 49, realise that that matches "multiple calls on separate threads" and is more likely than interruption. Look for intermingled high/low values after that to assess the likelihood that two loops are running at the same time.

Comment: How large are the messages you are sending?  What is time between messages?  TCP the packets can be very large.  You are only getting into the event after each chunk.  If chunks are 3 seconds than you will only get 20 counts of i in one minute.